# add expressions in cplex with java

Tags: java, cplex

I am using cplex with java and I am trying to solve this equation in cplex, for example,

U = A + B

where A and B are expressions, and U is the objective function , and all of these expressions U,A, and B will be arrays

This is a piece of my code

```
IloLinearIntExpr[] U = new IloLinearIntExpr[n];
IloLinearIntExpr[] A = new IloLinearIntExpr[n];
IloLinearIntExpr[] B = new IloLinearIntExpr[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
U[i] = cplex.linearIntExpr();
A[i] = cplex.linearIntExpr();
B[i] = cplex.linearIntExpr();
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

B[i].addTerm(1, P(X));

B[i].addTerm(1, C(Y));

A[i].addTerm(X, 1);


U[i].addTerm(cplex.sum(A[i],B[i]));  // it seems to be there is a problem here 

cplex.addMaximize(U[i]); 
 }
```

It seems there is a problem with cplex if we add two expressions, could you please suggest me in this issue.

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In `U[i].addTerm(cplex.sum(A[i],B[i]));`, you are trying to add an `IloNumExpr` to an `IloLinearNumExpr`, where method `addTerm()` expects only an `IloNumVar` and a `double` as coefficient of the decision variable that is to be added to the expression.

Try instead:

```
U[i].add(A[i]);
U[i].add(B[i]);
```